# using jfilechooser to save photo pathway and to load a photo

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jfilechooser, imageicon

I am using mySQL to store the directory of the photo that I select using jFileChooser. Once the file has been selected, I save it to the database. But when I retrieve the data and use the ImageIcon to set a label to the photo of the directory that i saved, it shows a nullpointer error.

i am opening netbeans in administrator and since the user is selecting the file, the file must exist i.e cant point to a null.

here is the code of the jFileChooser :

```
    JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
      file.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
      FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg","gif","png");
      file.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
      int result = file.showSaveDialog(null);
      if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
          File selectedFile = file.getSelectedFile();
          String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
          GlobalDataStore.imagepath=path;//this stores pathway so that i can save it to the database
          photofield.setIcon(ResizeImage(path));
      }
```

and code that saves it to the database

```
    String imagepath = GlobalDataStore.imagepath;// retrieves image directory
    {
        Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
        Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(conndata,username,password);

        Statement stmt = (Statement)con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String query ="SELECT name,admn_no,class,section,house,gender,sloganstore,picturepath FROM candidates WHERE post=\""+GlobalDataStore.selectedpost+"\"";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        int rowcount = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        for(;rs.getRow()<=rowcount;rs.next()){}

        rs.updateString("picturepath",imagepath);//saves it to the database

        rs.updateRow();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "data was successfully updated");
        con.close();
        deselect();

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        int row = model.getRowCount();
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
        model.removeRow(0);
    }
    }
```

and code to set the label to the image :

```
            String path=rs.getString("picturepath");
            con.close();
            System.out.println(path);
            ImageIcon photo=null;
            photo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
            photofield.setIcon(photo);
```

Comment: Are you soore it is correctly saved?Try printing the path before this line      `rs.updateString("picturepath",imagepath);//saves it to the database` and also when you are using query print again the `imagepath` to see where the problem is...

Comment: i am sure. i tried printing the path using the system.out.print in java and the path is correct. and when i am using my own try and catch, an error box appears with nothing in it